# su gives permission denied

Tags: centos, sudo

I have installed su to allow a security analyst to login to a VPS to make some changes who needs root permissions - I have created a user and they can login fine under their acount but as soon as I type `su`, `su -` or `su- root` and then enter the **users password** I get:

```
su: incorrect password
```

Logging back in as root, the user has been added to sudoers and permissions on su are:

```
-rwsr-xr-x 1 root root 35K May 23 11:00 /bin/su
```

What else could be causing the problems? VPS is running Centos 6.4

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`su` and `sudo` are different tools and work differently.

`su` always requires the root password to be entered in order to gain root privileges.

`sudo` requires the user's password to be entered (provided they are configured to be eligible for access) by default, but can be configured to require entering root's password as well.

You probably want to install `sudo` and use that instead of `su`.

Comment: It's not stupid. There's always the chance to confuse them, especially since they are similarly named and work similarly (just not equivalently).